# Why is this returning undefined? (freecodecamp)

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, return

```js
// Only change code below this line
var myArray = [];
function countdown(n){
  if (n < 1) {
    console.log('Finished array: ' + myArray);
    return myArray;
  } else {
    console.log('Pushing Value!');
    myArray.push(n)
    console.log('Calling function countdown');
    countdown(n - 1)
  }
}
console.log(countdown(10));
// Only change code above this line
```

The code feels like it should be correct, but the function returns `undefined`.

I think this has something to do with recursion...

(Rules:)

```
countdown(-1) should return an empty array.

countdown(10) should return [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

countdown(5) should return [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
Passed

Your code should not rely on any kind of loops (for, while or higher order functions such as forEach, map, filter, and reduce).
Passed

You should use recursion to solve this problem.
```

Comment: Your `else` case has no return statement. Did you mean `return countdown(n - 1)`?

Answer (score 0):

Beside the missing return statement

```js
// Only change code below this line
var myArray = [];
function countdown(n){
  if (n < 1) {
    console.log('Finished array: ' + myArray);
  } else {
    console.log('Pushing Value!');
    myArray.push(n)
    console.log('Calling function countdown');
    countdown(n - 1)
  }
    return myArray;
}
console.log(...countdown(10));
```

You could use an array as return value, without using a global variable.

```js
// Only change code below this line
function countdown(n) {
    if (n < 1) return [];
    return [n, ...countdown(n - 1)];
}

console.log(...countdown(10));
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is a functional heritage and so using it with functional style yields the best results. This means avoiding things like mutations, printing output in the middle of a function, and other side effects. Here's what a rewrite of your program could look like -

```js
const countdown = (n = 0) =>
  n <= 0
    ? []
    : [ n, ...countdown(n - 1) ]
    
console.log(countdown(-1)) // []
console.log(countdown(10)) // [ 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 ]
```